# Print source code of bash script with its includes

Tags: bash

Is there a way to view/show/print the source code of bash script with its includes (aka "sources")?

For example:

sub.sh file

```
 function showMe(){
     echo "INCLUDE"
    }
```

main.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash    

source sub.sh

showMe    
echo "OK"
```

The "print" of main.sh will show:

```
#!/bin/bash    

showMe(){
 echo "INCLUDE"
}

showMe    
echo "OK"
```

Comment: source code can be seen by `more/less/cat`, at run time you can use -x flag (e.g. `set -x` ). There is no such a magic that will statically print print source code, and included file. No equivalent to `cpp`  for C language.

Comment: How do you "print" of main.sh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk '/^source/ { while (getline l <$2 > 0) print l; close($2); next; } { print; }' main.sh
```

so each line which starts with `source fname` should be replaced with contents of file if exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p0e 'while(s/source\s+(\S+)/`cat $1`/e){}' foo.sh
```

Comment: Works great.. but I can't use perl, thankyou by the way.

Comment: put `echo "source foo.sh for the rescue"` in `foo.sh` and you get an infinity loop:)

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin, you are very cruel! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind executing the script too, here is a simple way to have the source code and its includes being displayed:

```
bash -v foo.sh
```

Comment: This command also parse the script, I need only the source, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Programs outputting their own source are called [quines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)). There are a lot, although it is surprisingly non-intuitive to actually develop one. Most examples on the net does not include anything. A simple bash version can be found [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashQuine):

```
#!/bin/bash
q=(
'#!/bin/bash'
'q=('
')'
'printf "%s\n" "${q[@]:0:2}"'
'printf "\047%s\047\n" "${q[@]}"'
'printf "%s\n" "${q[@]:2}"'
)
printf "%s\n" "${q[@]:0:2}"
printf "\047%s\047\n" "${q[@]}"
printf "%s\n" "${q[@]:2}"
```

There are quines in practially all programming languages. There are also quine chains (outputting source code on another language, that source outputs the original). [This quine](https://github.com/mame/quine-relay) is a 128 language long chain.